# PDF with hyperlinks: disable printing of link "boxes" in Preview app

Tags: catalina, pdf, preview

I am creating a lot of PDF documents using LaTeX.

Prior to Catalina, when using Preview, embedded hyperlinks in those PDF documents were shown with a red or cyan border, but that border didn't appear on printed copies.

However, since my upgrade to Catalina, this seems to have changed: whenever I print such a document, the red or cyan border remains visible. Also, when I open a document and print it/export it to a file using Preview, the border is there, but just as a graphical object. The link itself disappears.

The following screenshots try to illustrate the problem: on the left, the red border indicates the presence of a link. When hovering over the link, the mouse pointer (unfortunately missing in the screenshot, despite having the corresponding option switched on) changes to a hand and a tooltip is shown. On the right, the border is somewhat thicker, but there is no link anymore.

[image: working link]
[image: link no longer working]

**For reference, below is the original PDF file (as generated by LaTeX)**, base64-encoded (to decode it, save it to a file and run in Terminal `base64 -d <file name> > ~/Desktop/file.pdf`):

```
JVBERi0xLjUKJdDUxdgKNiAwIG9iago8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDEzNiAgICAgICAKL0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVE
ZWNvZGUKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnjaLU67DsIwDNzzFR6dISF23iNIdGDOhligReoCiPL/wm26+GTfw3dq6jAw
QbU1cYL2BArR1hAhxWzZR2gjXJGsNtE5HHTx+NaGs8xbu4ADQ+LlXce77rho473HcVoe3/kuhoLT2G/z
a8WAnx4jq8Cvc7SFkrymUsDEkLcuvcPKqXNTfyUiKLsKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoxNCAwIG9iago8
PAovTGVuZ3RoMSAxNTkxCi9MZW5ndGgyIDEwNjEyCi9MZW5ndGgzIDAKL0xlbmd0aCAxMTY1OCAgICAg
Ci9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp42o23BVCc6RYtijsEl2ANwd09uLu7Q2OBBprG
IbgnIQQL7gQaDxCc4ASH4O7uLkEumZkzM+e8V3VvdVX3v7bv/a39Vf+0VOparBLWzpZAWWcQhJWTjUMI
IKWiyckB4ODgZuPg4EKjpdW2hzgC/xKj0eoCwW72ziChfxlIgYEWkGeZtAXk2U7FGQRQdHcEcHIDOPmE
OPmFODgAXBwcgv8xdAYLAaQtPOytASpsAEVnENANjVbK2cUbbG9rB3lO859HAIMVI4BTUJCf5Q93gIQT
EGxvZQECqFhA7IBOzxmtLBwBWs5W9kCI93+FYBCxg0BchNjZPT092Syc3NicwbaijCwAT3uIHUAT6AYE
ewCtAb8bBqhaOAH/7IwNjRagbWfv9qdcy9kG4mkBBgKeBY72VkCQ27OHO8gaCAY8JwdoKSgD1FyAoD+N
lf80YAH8NRsAJxvn3+H+8v4dyB70h7OFlZWzk4sFyNseZAuwsXcEAtRkldkgXhAWgAXI+rehhaOb87O/
hYeFvaOF5bPBH5VbAGQlNAAWzw3+1Z6bFdjeBeLG5mbv+LtF9t9hnqcsA7KWcnZyAoIgbmi/65O2BwOt
nsfuzf7nyb4BOXuCfP8CNvYga5vfTVi7u7DrgOxd3YEK0n+ZPIvQ/pHZAiEAXg4ODn5BbgDQFQD0srJj
/x1e29sF+IeS87f4uQN/XxdnF4DNcxNAf3sb4PMPmq+bhQcQAAG7A/19/634b4TGyQmwtreCACyBtvYg
tH+iP4uBNn/i58MH23sBjDieuccJ4Pj9+fvJ5Jle1s4gR+9/zP84X3ZpTT1VCWXmPzv+Wycp6ewF8GXl
4QCwcvFyADh/k4z/+cH/v8OoW9j/Vca/fBVANs4AwT+rfR7Tfyr2+IsADH8tByPgv2OpOj+zFghg+Ifk
xhy8HFbPX5z/z1T/w+X/j+G/o/zfSP6/Bcm6Ozr+oWb4Q///UVs42Tt6/2XwTFp3yPMCqDg/rwHof031
gH8urQrQ2t7d6X+1ChCL50WQANk6/j1GezdZey+gtbo9xMruT7b8Kdf5vWWO9iCgurOb/e9rBcD6fDT/
o3teLas3z1eH2zMl/1ABnzfnv1PKgKycrX+vGBcvH8ACDLbwRns+5GfEC/DlfN5Fa6DXHyQGsLOBnCHP
LoDn9vwBNs5gtN8nyscLYJf4LfoD8XMA2GX/RoICAHbLf5AggN3qb/S7Vnbrf0FOADvwX/A5rP0/8JmP
7KB/wWdj578hz3Pg5/vxX2ouALvLP2q+Z/RMFOd/ZePkAbCD/wWfs7n9Cz57QP6Gz5Njh3j+me6/Rmfl
DgY/3x5/kPt5rv/Bf1xVQKAX0AptdsrZSjjU4Wto802lBKkn6+bw63HaTb3PjKy+s+AW9zss5ETGivTg
ZfCVRGJfB/bCugzDpfgc5YPvfkMNckRjvEbTL797szjNsc0mtJlRwp6R/H2J6m5yVDJWbfEtvwdXP92g
N/ANsN8VabNd3QWw1HPxbjy75Lyqu6Hzg+FTmxpbFXxK6PfQn6zvdd4ZB32ZoM2xzJgkpkaCsJKjMOGe
eL2YuLwax80aeaJUjGNG8z94z13ga7jC9eF20mexVJvLrY2EhsSQmBz+EndwjM5XcidJkWjat6hgoWfG
q0GkgDILkyV5gRWbbYcrrcJeMwZU11nlMTjbyrmRnQgIpSftwduIryquwzcDU6sRVDSZxeBBqrjfAMl3
Wm0kF5uvdNttHJLJ5gR/Vj8BJjAN7PYD69t9f9W4Lvb197Behyc33vTV9a+3++t9EesWI7P15GSSsTOK
XpgXSiNPRoRChuDa9IAK+Ngscx6JAveIFmEivsGnkncvOdfyOTgMBRA7YQfJjniz/U4/+JfVnqi2rkzg
TDt64pqEPIXwqT5Zfk8+OcknseOWMU8PZ8hJk2mPylmKpdcQ/gqsnQiBsp+slBGySRd7Uyp/WuOdOe2l
KeBRkOvcnC7vizYO9na4FcxjO9It02n6yJunQbVxEMM6tFMb9EMyJKxL8Mp6Z+2qpETSlGDXWff2pMwz
UrLvw6o2f2hOVKtmYFabm1qKnEQMXOH1+mQnquWrQ21JDyqnutgXetqv79aH2grvPVmgCtK09AWzKt1K
uyIRfrMmM9IFnSSVgeKEUZd1gVxfW9RuGGAw0rEXP9Cmb83DvzJr6avTPX18KUmqpX2T+8pnBaZz+ufQ
OtXA2DqNr2OZ8ReernqAMO+7FHjHODqq6fXA1PPl1wzvoh9touuXdDwlaubIqtImeoDLBz8GESRfIbdw
c+CLDh/IA/KL6dOXlAuY8Z+m4jMd1nwyxO8oY+tfl7sZf13CvxQJK3lt3GYAS7MsLRaps4c6unXPl5j1
00suRwPUW0KaGk2yYV9BO5WQSTU9hqbMBUNUZZSZinOxXhDASPXOJkw/GMVqBycGBWZdZJIe/8fX2KRT
TTx1bpkcqlBWoSocepyVx1EJLMUXFWyIs11fpRSHYRQhUBi6Tl9+pI98VWivgnRHO0fb9ien5CdJ489j
2Iv7sWSnbT2pZXkTYj1PtSJp/Cqegpw1RIa3h5PR0cfM334TyaDg5Cj2Q0l5EmnadTquqbudSV/qsztZ
yg5dLtsNRKmtraxME+sjMRc750/aJ0Q3G8xGNEpsPRfwUhfh4ZwkP38NGbmRh5l7gSnMl9JQ7w9Wcufc
5f6VqiMFg2ifSlgjDyn7Ojbuf+VNTDH1+NaKgtZ42fU40LixcYtHjceDyijN7FqhMbfyuLrinqBnyyrm
JccyecmZiuKtSpYBR+lgrIcv3zJxwpTxTScADpzl2pdKzU3y+ho+IUP7p4ES24IS8V4fYzsLkVy/kq9F
pJShpFxmCxoFufc8A1a0En14J5cax7hucjmfgjoNjeOv3bvSetZ4ohWjNuL9CeBQX8xN70sUEqXBaTou
WtsEywqfiGvFQZIUFnfntyqlXF3EPkvun1KyIyb4mFKbmAoxuzswS8aeBL8PFy2LdeUpJRBaMRIPjFyv
Gp/YZkHK6MSK1z+MdF38AiFp73u2xG8102RbqxpL1aflD8+pXU2NiBfocXlR7gi4Uilb/yxfJ3Xef7vB
qcv+7ofka/Gqi7tDKo5P7QY5zj63NIe3o9e9gbRdZd/H+gg8V5dWuUycoZ3LgHKzBzEFu4EX7js5kk5H
skhEQrWcWCgzSdYoxT+8+a6D2+aWAOSymEWhxMogXq0zT7pi1v3xyopMOZ+bIsE94tc/6D9tMAw+NCvc
26ne1Uz5bqjhArA+c8Ire1hNOhEg2tcWttH9oFY52HPqEq/TmwwvI84vc1qwpOWY/YzIdGeeuo/clRO/
HM9uc9mZ4dhCqy7DlSNEoSvBqCWpzL4lAiU84sWDSmVK5C1fZzgKl/sOtKEzvGqc0UcEySJ9okaJgfkM
Eyrgqznj/AmnvUubiGHDTO8EzlLiMUDJz1kF3QxvajxZD2f5kSyuBdN7Q2XniS+wJLvKtOXaApJJiSKu
xrmfw54BI3tKmfCN25viVcq61QsVlelRuW7Dh0UjeKfSp0afkXeyAUiouI7Q2xLqDkXRciDCjK5krJ4k
mf+2LuNHhAWtH/P2JCw5x0FLX441cQnrCQtammTf98JDW9Qz2HZalBHGAr1uEAqJzYyG9XUjcYh6zy80
siswtdWfLj1Csm/RgP0sn1we516GgAPs4u/q490JTz+GvjNndvR9iXIN1Lie+mgmbkPEx/1SflndwmPM
h0RniMCsMmsIv8ewhJOCCbrR+x63IlaFudfSJTBc2HcROogaVKbBTbijqys8k9M8FDmOhYlbrsamlrli
z9IsIFAyRRFy0BkeZpv12vj1iji17MqdkuyNdo7lr89xrbpBHxwZHG3L2zPmLH+WvV+kqt+BTiZNDhiv
Ptxa8GhwElUOvgWUCK656hbUfxksAHxyM31zmOtm/SENhOUT146CXJa3nS80Raac6UNi8gHnBApGjy7I
hYZ4qEq3xqjI8QvSKCjbP9LFS8zYkq6CHPm8YSMUUWNl1WrPRJRQN/fVh/LVPkhIEPd7hMcHLP10zKXb
rr0x2JyuoZ8dhtGbG90MoWvL5QhSAjySEKSy26Paz/50R7XMfNkhhSbQ2+UjIV8wmcUNi+bNdmaU7dWw
tgjhlHAvg2ZguEiMsBnx5GnNcFl6JjBbASDF+UeqwJfEdmTSg18X0bupU6go3m6UCDPzuxjne3qR4Bqs
yaGZLvLKlA8t7MQT4JJlmS00JMnVXq+e7AYyUEhgONbhjR1xmi8IuLOduzMfrc9S352LCp+wBPj01YzR
ojk3VSxne8H/4PjsFowz9YMEV49T1mvkaGIneRlg++gU977WS9f7snYOZyyD2uSVz1vi5C8uHmftmBnk
4XEpVzPdRWxgScEoGgJQvYFUmRTnXRcEai3+6rpIAGb0jWrERIxSJWz2uHBe295EvGOQ7B0DEvrMO9Xz
6EJY4ZXVAuvH0o5fh7CfyrDvl5mao0V6CnMS17vxQvGg8G5thYIitXKxmFIy5mG6u7l2Ky19XbQEGvHD
sgXO6i1da2M4IQE00I8t1GPc3M3X6oLTggeG790EI2DpzdfLKDAPwHN6t0KqCQUHP9zGL3sT6ijFkWxC
MNJNyfUWw+i4eDxxix190LdoJrj0jvG+ei6G9RyoCVo+5W1SqxVm4fUP6XUyyeKaLLIXmntD32lUoUb2
JRhrJHaQyjJBF+y1CU/f75iqAq6szfJUzEPyw7VotatVG5X4YytQmDVTpg6MwAVp9z8MLrvxDg1cgf7N
VTNkGAUx1zMGEep3F2jDsrA6MrkH54/vTsaVQtomX8i/o/9aKwprqCE+/EJhdgVCm7fxlJTeZlTEyN9F
13qfbTcMysCoItk1oJ+Yt+j4pt15Sq8PDphYTmEHmYES4RWVcwjRURiSxNG+bmcPjKaildWqkvsqydYu
z5+YvkmzXOoA7b0lPDRXrsgzQZm3yNfJgW3o9r2PxPVYO1ZeXmjcyuWJv+D8TBOAB3aSeDpyS8Tv6Dk/
AxkuwzOlNL0uvu53uzxxTsO3FPeN855CR6GSkqKM8SWyQmHTCzD8dnBMscVBBEJfsXQJs3VT/2xNwzpm
fFUxPJFGpyzi8h0Bt/6FIx6GX8PbtBqBnTu2vq6kb8w2w70+3kUeIZSrZl8lfcr7I7LCL7jEPCaaUZDg
9s6bL6cjOvVhLfKoBEgm853QkuYjiG09Z6mQ0VBu+DdlUQ3EvbVM3p6GZcGllN06OktO7ZbGo1ImZXhQ
cdzu1EXLJgRjLC7fHRXLLFsYRQbb3Kh78QTKh2UT+O0h693XCM/LUUzhYxvgUXNLXvDOnt9v3azKG1OP
lxgh3XAmDaccWvGq3ghCXUS5+BWbJB/Oa93Y4Y+iv9kyXBR7EWiwYEFEjcrXBIbi5dy664OEKDVpBE34
8Oki75y8yxnta0miPfp2HTqu9IpilLs0JU3JNSUtHL/ve1WbZU8bZAh95VX5UoGwvHU0j38cjYz3oans
RS1pQNEvdof8sJXu2Rwq/yXzhKN9aTo9ssAf0I0pDf0GGiT55S/bLwYhCvllzagBPybZZg3ITsVnQAQl
4CRss4sD0EJQBwpmq9r9OkRCFZFVGROUFJMshmi2RGhqFjZvi/+p9m0mYU+s8HtzisrRwyIlyYilEz5g
17f2BcqKuHo00YQdx+8aLnHhL0tyA8YZ28K/ZdzWFpyxvxdG1iKhxzBtuBTagCAoVjmI7+F7lVSHyDBw
yPULDzcSzGu4wn0o7k14o03fcJKJLZwp8tGVFDSz4R4EcVSW4ozX7wLwDr1MRnONm+5y/VkQJLYRM+rD
KaXF3EaWp87Z+ZYC2AenxTWEzl2imKQy1x+a6MhwOl5Lg0LRCOzT2GR3clHlVeKH1XsARvsxds7PLFlE
yyeVrRg2jFfwuL/X8f/e3bXdeVGEhK8DGKMaSDJIPNiDuaWagFVAmTDYLBrPIlGi3bEqkKmoP6D4lfZa
cnZQwYQ0UAuJ8xrw6ny8EccOa9BII1zZDmrAuhn8Vgv86G3BC1BRN5ArnhwVphBEeE9mglA8RmQAQxgT
Js4b+GlxeYzhJdpNepwoekZnSF2ftLxDRC72uhsBmCDYayEJbYutQ3RudKqiImfkTXL5nGOXMF1SxSuR
7bnUyjPgR0absQ1ZnzTzut46sdx1BSsYcS15uiSRJ8TmT0cIQA8QjABeUIZsMJnxum4VlLv73KJMgsrb
u3ld6HScGT/TiirP6wQxKdhyROVxKmqV3cafezkpbX+gsHedWq44Cadsm95GxW0MeYJSX0/nwf/+qrau
3qCr9r0peuDENK3DUC+VfOtxjJr8E0rf0AdKs9tvMcI7EV+HzwLi1hTrPXKwvgaZLLxCo5lFhr6Yp5ey
EwviTREJ1SJ+IG86HKhsPxWPLyPOQE21KK0JZMVPkQiwig7fdXTWg61RYTiLRQLD1H15NW8+PQoy8HWY
N+f2c4TzIC83b6RXcMx+CFipotqsuc+5HFfv6D/wTchFkqn4fPx62MVixxQ9aMZuX+0NvHlG3VHausvN
HUaZgLv3Ag34LGnxPNEdzcbfyrWTmbfd+y3Vw6LJZMYd6U3bAZYOSxlsKySbccteSP4su1UtrGueodwM
qBa0Sy6r2/roOopEKFrqvrPSxSonFLl62uUTkhmWJm9oTBurc+gx0wZDgTnqs25KvDIg+d6bNlBVe63+
G/dr4nL9/RWxZid8xU83hKzj3KHX5Pbr0/LiCx+DbEZCHt7Ua7Ltp10+eNAH9jqx4dIPaa13SDcNzjp6
31MS88cT5mIYXE5JVZd1O+3Wmn6rkHPnNZNLQ76pneUs/PUCwv5uAv1x5f3g2gnaCk9UFWcZKNLsl7So
vwsS85YN1FbQjob8rqgb1kT8WOXWfMb0Z4Oc0pUwbwlSvmfvfhPChgLY9ViiiNtGInjZAMfevTSwY3Gj
86xl7PjgJ64BGHuXXPrySij2/Zw1BbJmAfwiIF4CgoOxzwr9yILPuNZoAc3va7RbGxE0mvji/oSitU0s
qPSJJBSnS1up2EKfZsPTti/+m1qI0RqcVwypa29InjeCAkPSU7MDNq/yF6hCm1Wtv58dRRtNnI/0Gp7O
SMdHzyaD98wtD6WGQsPH210j+d3pnN/Pah0DZoFtpL2w5u434nAv/RBKDygJphYid2pSe0zn+EiP2DO9
x36ZW5zk4Bb+wIw2qhiOxjb/2Took5nX4fmyHfHAgoIUI8dny/5M2SKUCNffob9yu0/8V170pn93gNeL
rWO9b4jIKZugCLcPnzlATFi+WBWOYobFPucxif24MaL12wKHlC6symN0P/J+wR8rmYsCzGuKaDvMk3KP
Fr/3uUHFGj0GmnpMje+jmD4RTD1o9K8WqVrahDHPN7cuhWY6U6O+n/2ig9rsM3Zuu2c7ZLHx4aN7jWz2
WIpIJ57+nfdiPbR0FO6OqRnuh+3VE4+YPpdJx0eeIvnUody06bNU0/ZRV2Wg89f0zzqH528xrgs+fRrl
Fz1g7Mk/T5EHfcyEaywqk+Cn3vWVDtcUYeeCPKh0917cum0WBv56I6igf/HJJq84fQx+7Wnk4Rcz3myh
vszBlyTsH2x7q1Rto53UTIrzWvxYbXMGFBUoZDuIxw7zmOR0P2cldhQxmEu2Ir83NKHgzuG+vkxSzdmk
4fP4qvVS2wAn6tU8cbly8hPP8JejbbE0mBH6q4PrztsAWSJrXTnlKRbmbUI3glK5x/wVU/b6YteaToS+
K1i7d90vSm9vDSlKfUKliyHiGNzXQNzUtKwdlRlxUQdGET078w2V5kjRp+ncvqe3q8CVQ11pxUm/5MZG
/Rf+Y1+kwNE/iHq0f0j82EG3IX6A+5z3KUHdXxgxmnq8Welq/NVwnHZ2HZbs9Z3x9suHa9OJeHjyl/Do
wimobX57mgBp465gTHn3Cb4nje6H0c/0GRrcPyyFvV7Vf6DkPqfUGhSCOljiHM7T1kMU45DZRftz1J6O
0snBuktBHSReJpUNSM2ijGvHWe21JoGOGbfwvM6t2EbbOaOywtgsqnRF9Hj2xdHGVaoa7Qpn8hNDF6OU
bWLaQofiM7LHRNuqT+jIWvrtixxVIqWMTXYrelNIQS08Ng2y0nV2sfNsM9XacIymWohjrBRhIE//Bxb0
SEPVehmCUSnYi4prdAP095qIwFqfjomrE+7mn8Zo32Ygh4+PBqu85rFEsm/N0rza34fA62T6xdDrf6rt
jQiVE3+hM4XNp4BuTJkSur1wJXov1Kdr9guuT3SyUJBJgcOfcLzWmNp3hgDlmFtnzqfntM99QzbdBn5w
Nj/sUn25qJ9R5mOkwIvge52C9DtPxvITW7zoAQLXCaEVa4dXBQ0VCwSRdsiuvegF6c1uzpisDeKf0JTg
5fhj16nL/DRGI+C2oHebAMMzHze/sGD/vC7lyRotvOgCoUAb6KRT85cOCe7j2KkTLXSurtckcVNG1dZ1
M/H3iunGC9WEFGVkZ4RWB3PEgfe3L/yQBiCtDpxjPWkS2+DHaILytrHyR5JBRY8OFiVKP1jUs5qwkUTd
pY8f09E+36dphNYYLSyJ6LTrC5EhBM/Ni1kxX9GuVKEeqjYtSGrxCobfhLRXw76HZlJ3TnWlV9vuaO82
L26YWhbrdaMgzTN8ZaIBvPNEKr3ZYSSIfhe/HmaKr0oFLus08CkQKQinIwInC0tYK0iRmrNHBvmjsToA
YPl8jAccz14MPkSnK/G8ZBoKUmIlmV7UK9DaVI8ZKpeAytGHdBF2LdwRVY/+HJQ55poZlVfnbyeqoDg0
2NDrY/0q24croxI3bZL6QzJqLYsGF8bklItWRKNha+3tFryd6SrF+u7gQWVAXu+ruV5f60IXz7FQchj7
O/s9SmcUQXD8kI4vyGfAn0/L5Py1utn6IWFQVK02oFlD20WjQFXT6Ev0tZpz/oOeGh+UzbpnteylONX2
dPKOhOnLcqJtJfTyBak6YVrIwuBUWBM74pYWc71ej6XRy2rJN5Gxr5z05tkN1asDlvVYLF/nv/wVaJ9G
ra1lV+F4PEUoG0DUZIa4/Tm9qQfhqZ/4NDSscrF1CLeO7JhfDwda2mD+s2mkBNK356AWIycHEv98aM+j
c8OOGqvwJO/BftX6wo1dZ4G6tJPE9KN43VLbTr3E471UYOn+g0vhkMZEUzLCpMJA/NvxBVHRc7w50L3O
eAX2Nznkd4Wg+g97714jG5Jdq5cOgeU/Ic/+IJ+x9PhQYuTsJaLAn/AdV50N4V4TSdVqFPEMXpHCAZLk
b+uN2uTtryPAUiDSSK/nCwVsiQ0rMeoU9yZiuUhNuyPZJuTOYVGHPL8t10ZfvXscQOUU05OpZFb69gLb
f9ugpznFK0r85mDA4br0JyEero/CF5UcCzn9VNbXZUtpVYVC4nJ7gMW1nw97D/KrScFoSPaG6COgm0AQ
PMg0/6DFCyYGKXEdk8eT1vSKzAAt2DV1bkecmpH4bsj08Zxu3bbu4HJ5TQ1k2qVccSjobJcvQvcdLxhu
izU0EKFbFanutv86g/wlIu8j4ZIg6hwOF5BPD7/1fmAsy/QhKNjyYxBJBuq8p+HPG7NsX+GCCAYOxSid
k3i/Q1nxENhv56fS/ou/uOCvdHg12ZhXoCwtbL3MHYvdpbuGEeGff6IRJaPZuveNXUD8wtLSZoOUV13X
NUUNL4CS4WwyFr73fKNvo3DQsKRHcmWRCPaxayYOSr9xc9I5yW5NX+/pvmy43ofnoJygGx6JccHYbZPQ
dNVQHMnJYM5gY/muY3SucIHBGb3bWkj/Imb3OorErVm7a8cdz/nBJZWgRJN6JPDDsYWiRMDGyduXOx/f
uYdjfKikgdJ/n4IH8G8P+jAxGsz1Z72z88N902rvUOjG2pjhGjjQ4BITbtNd88Nvye+iYHK2PoOK2vJS
KDuNAMGbkDyG3WxhDwbw0PvlrGrpu+ErZKpNInXcENtsKDjBOCH+ypD37va42M+siAiuTV6gnpiRk+ll
u3kdTk2CnuppuoWUTMXe1VQJrrkNXZ7fIPlIIZIvCYLSVKD8haz1WKk2ncEA/hq9Aj9DSK4lPoaqLf7l
9JsqVHbbc7lqF4sEAEqGqLteWJxxMXwP/KF+pdkXpYQHFOXaWM79B9Nma3GFCFfCjAkfHv5stkvd2XNm
JAqvbmUIc+5x6HDiNgk2yKCLalpLVb6N+DhsKrqheBslgugt14jMJb3dNxRHif2FppraLP+EJ+49rqDu
dc2a6a522yiExoo+Bnv8943te/KfyHbXhhwapfri+G0X83VX67X1B04Wq+eCKcdFtxUWUe3rHh37Rsgw
EvpjkIRAGrn756402mosNkyfP+tmYmeUmNe7lLH5l7Km46BprnF22CI4quaCxTcIEMZ3NLItNBmlPq71
KQ9K571jWSs1pS7R64rssZUDkxVKHGvCnz+1d0+93RYziuI9YJZ62pd23olaEbLmTevGm+kMlU5153XF
yFea1fdpzZtP0ThKWDAzrCrEudgdw7BCshfbJi2jh7ypjKGG/eBBB+nUbzRKPhiBrUCYNJD9isbwS46Y
0mBJyUgb2fntliY1hvFPND3DOL9Mf2rZaJJMU0/azyIPPDIQhFOjIlOyuaVagZlJ6jkm02Xx1NZP1wR5
SVhRO4nxrAgvvXVqijnE95W2mXPW8VQbMIwbZVvvNmACX9s65uFDbpIwnH+1hIhP9OkBU9cXHEK7eVL5
vS2pbRUnnHMCjC3L0otfOQn3lN7Q8/eiDKAy351+LZVSNLuU2hnfxndMhSXzLSLWC+RfSbHccJROWfUh
fhOqIaA+mQBZWv+8IGBMxWCNIrjWz2vCyk8P4YJ7fU/ur6xGYyricuEpJwzWC6yK7z3ZqkvSWNkcp7EV
QYHfAvIZZcfEJisNSgEIva8nqgWzTsKEFnzQ89IQRuLk4FZsC1MM7h85vQmvzyicvvYg330xfwQkPjIe
tuIKiCfaqUaVLSGZN2MevzH4Zg/mEt+5iGtJhL1VJ51Nql9MSdVVU3NumdGID3x7T26R3LTBerrMOeYc
m5s4iHwJKRpPSxY0ku1KaH5hTIlDKt8aOK4urCUVGfPuxhanmLjk7E0mviAOJaPWuxw2VPJpYKrKhunp
GUFisAzSG7wARKkaY8ehb4LhGQ3fpJ/Y9KUgevs2StSWn8+EGEt3kvy8Y65iW7XCr4JDjaJpFsFgq+Vl
gwsHK9DRViEzCBd/2EDkg4P0Mm5T5PqXKl7BXVgq7vF+eOVEC0ZSRIOuBpvCy28+DXbzRu1rgkgydBY2
95mpUfPw6Zkp5usEg5iGEByeKtix5kvh11HFqsUukz5HASTtMs50F7J1FDieyzNO6Tl0KOTHXDRaKr9w
jcdXtuXVqtEtgwkEam2WLcYVn1+QEhduR+mqJdDzuHkC+7obMaKI6macVJxZyfI4Bnz004WdJ76anyZ3
y/fqjP5YQkNbC/qQJg/FdU+JSqaZyS0oFO22ihD+iFutKbQeKcSPxt3r/jaHnbJ4QATrMnKFia+CAFl6
Ps7xy7qWiNsdvlEI7QH5fgFNirmAak29alcvRdwMuGpe+O0GudL6zm4Y+gjud3NUMc/QeqpvekL1j3Qh
aaa+9E+f1eDYV1lfK1x13MHmVmZ9haUnKm1uGrfigldpX1vf8rh8J11wpBJQosz/LY907zE/uMBbb0Tm
wiUH0Twu0xbXeaOL9Dz4+JBLqVcgdU2QQs1kCMeA5rs4jQNx0SxUj+2bk1k/92Ya/nm2MzhiPCLe/x3S
lQY1OM1c2HG4TRMwRKxyXnQlE2ycpYmdae02wRQjDBsO6/QlDpn6/SGp4g/Ijq+HTyqKvYoWGFuOL3c7
lnk1B85EoK0j6qOkvglsQSoUQKqG1LsTwoJtaWZUPNpGw0bv58WAM2JR7SruWdtEInw+FcEhe6oahtnm
Xb5VOLD861b6cQbTU4r6DXzzGC/YJPBCSYRvJ0YQSOxmuQqZUkPml4wv6r7dZqFcJTMMgyIzFEz0dlVU
Y+UV3fqZAWoU10f3G5/YCeHWP0+Gf331QnthBioy7NQrkVJb6i3m6tmCkEU6aFCywDGSTNtrm0yV7IwJ
L4cdIyE3cmqkUr2oM6prd4HIF5LYOHTh4TI4QHJD2LTaeD20ijoYGVP9WjwNaXIPPIcJpbJtZhQ47MXX
XKkDcp2G+Syri0YFzdtiXA6MZhKB6IxP5XNhMoign21uXsK1nCvcVTGeiYb3tVjeI2bLhel4ZHZ0SajP
KGT3ztp8PQKKLBML5C2evsqpPUJv8WaOkLlpQaGqR2on8bqDrhtbRWcfvkVp0t3WjkH/3nefFCbOOtLd
c3jZUTH9TcghzqvcclSiFT2sDRp/i5RY8IV65jvL51ZHj/ekKASV5tiJc99kPpgjwNL4V5yhONUeaco6
OS1xO+UswS0GnzydE1CmH+/gt6Q5TTTgtScpahlbG3nbHRStE3Xzx2Hxv28UOv7F7Inqpn9LJR+X8wsj
JUQM2NQqKsUQ11ubIUGArCywVSLK05zlCCfyfcCjmRVEZCe64+05HIsMO44kzYTmma8tSZPvRo/i60Hl
QPKmBX8gqAK2mgQpcJQGpDUXgnpCYCcyUMA9nOrjnn0zta6ZXXc4aOh07ldlaQOUZaWsSZ9aJtV66moK
D7x2U9+uFIEIbxb/ZCHJQzXoxJBPGGEX9d5PwKE09cX1+YjI0chmIycIuB1X0ZjmTPLTsLIAt75wWWJH
CDnbSosbdE09r00oh/OMHYZp9xw0ipwyV9gUvUAp+e5CvsH8M+xqSyH7y9S9UlqFwrr5fbFga+HU0Zxq
Weon80WTKEOpz5qQxK4xkcRzeQhtHFZVA9r5Fo7Ni4gNuaHVcJrJB1FzZImCwd3zDAiBr8kBL5rCwptN
BuwHDnGZRhrynUVVNycG8xreEFBuxFXU9ENNvNl0wrZJ60BrpNdbfKIT+Qaxw07d+I1zOTKRGMpJvGDY
s5Y7aMPER0914Q4wICFAoyiIcnU3mzwTeW3ocWpt6bvfarR9WL1dZ60teCtNINx3DxwwenOYnOQRBV9k
TFJzITm9V3YaGQm6yoP0hpNPVJrQ+VcyVaxn1oBKKLpT/zjs73iFbTb7fdM7Ph5hhL0VODCGnoqEsO55
6X1vGWPUEghkTCImmSkxs7XIcejXBVqi0klWVnSWorlB/RoLmFXfS7ikm8vd9dH3Mm6FSKg8qbjfB1Fj
0Fc7Tt9GvbBJXmV3H7hgVVZm+e5Kmlu7BqaQGBCGz22qxo84QlVBXZYd471ZIjhjOPETdcgH3a+9HbsK
fKxnqPOWEASaEQYil1e6acyH+FaKJCy1zyAu8o+szRXkQ1V2wLkbv2QJMgfhRTQkNZbgajeUYSRnfOqt
XedCzmKzjOaSSsk6ZlXXdkQG1E76+fmSDVUCvHY+2vrBDKNVa1hUJ5gNwsloX3+r7I8gmaHqbF2lQefw
3samGuRN/ZBq1dPArnwn4TeIrICiW6CD4tpmjUr2LrJrl5DhHhMo0kPgYfD8UlHouH2kmZY6vuxOKk9n
6mpQtcnLxrMXXGFq4b5bXWFrA7/IVN9aLxzf5nu/OFAPo4+cLJnZxeNKjm/DEEjbNIqz1mXhuUCNeAZd
TMi4+7qmRJVnjmiLPfj5yHb3SE+HPUsuRrz8iMQhTcNZDfP81x7SpCF0Ed6KojaFbo/JqlWCpQvqjoc0
o2BeRmDgZLcWT0d9/6ZG2K80CGmNDRL9w25+oR+oM1Ot2Px0iAE5H+/FwJSKFXX9Kc+Hh9xDFZru8c3p
kdCEUVX45cFPS3Sl/jpbXhgsVAshPmZwFXJGyAwbPKvC07v9pVJ8IreK3OvggFKG3e3uzY9Kkjo6mBNZ
5fsW+xTDm+sKjr02t8SAU3Z5YfYis/ddimm2mj+N0BcWB9uYXqXbL8Vnj9i3e5ruIvkwkE/VOC7XSq7w
8rxKfCnHCoNi4YX61X1euDkPW0M5EJSZ0SZcyR4UvySK2cFQ32pSHCbGS/o5nknpsHNHjClcUOUdYHuY
ymVHv6Rkp//60PP1F4+VZCUV6fyECs+0nHWFyPqMfQzJcqMimVfgGZe+OFbfTtkNfo/djhDSUcReRiXa
d8oynuvZfoa9u1njh1vJrsGXW8gOoEuO+kvxya2RM4MuuFxkxDdij7Gxr53TC91BwoqoCgUn2FuTgZ2N
5998XmZQJm80TLP1F0iif4WceqL1eJSsv13oRGtutmETIyJjUuFModJjUcLa+IEtvlesfxn2NQRBpeom
2TNvm6PjzvT72a6sDOZPEGq6CPdJQjrqgG0NtKy/lXH1Ru3B91NK+RA09wUGQp6u7l1lSkDpOnnDmpKk
bngv3SdrDAsSeOMmfBiwrt3CmzR1rc1UCpAHQ81wkXU3el3JQVzU/oUvuVA4X3j4K/e+IQ3ZwAYu7sny
kWoMDWDvaYVp/I6SIIFeSYVkpb4Kw9VONsnoK33HUodkQbJAR5ROaM9LZopbj02EZsaI3cAUXcsQZGjj
gn0kjJ3XvUnejo6qZErHclqdmUJb0XnP7V7Z8FlRsslBXD6XzYx2GPMrsAb4O5Zy2yprmOVw/JluNGxd
33XZTqPDrQt7eNkr/UrISFje9wIOhsn6a0JHD8YqRWl0o9LPGE82uIvS4uMjNJ6Q78p94psUERRFUDuj
aWTR1zi8Q2TdkqYDddvWnhahfGZ2SlDcGDaBlkmeJAM/LPzgc9c2+xEv3owSgQut/YBpjmZH/fcESzz3
J4UwPkrgBNoKun6uvGt08ehS/z5rFolkgWacJePX/f1HrSGJy69B51GayKRsLt0ApL1KaLQh6bldlVFi
sdJHR0vxbzZ49FoCqkyOyE7vSxjppm5a4+7Ov3AZJCzU5QS4n6Yx/QoVWiuqYv1Yfh0bIevpry8dyaxL
4q+62N2x4or6E/erTyRWrgNVYygs0g81Q/LOcmQczGSWWLwmlLP0/fWds+la8kh2dCsJNKLXM16DZR7g
peoIlIkA6ic4qi9ZmsFIqjFOYowDrlqbDM2sEfvpmFgT3CtnJTll48y+zlQ+2otvMWOFRm31pP3TmM2f
/w72pOAL82InZk0v2yKK5psJrAhApNnFNlEzLpdcvvD0aLWKZaLyu48E2lginWYnze6fYmEFSp+dfVZL
8G/56WGK/xC+EsupKGKma1NCUxDCJ8OkgMWGln9IzTrIjMFbc9asbCrXi8fcIMzujTP7Y2WR+ZqoLJAS
wSzBKRSgCMeKylLTBdcwFJS7uvWCconEW9ZsKiS8RIod/5dzFww97QFj2kVX8A3hQz7HBm4omnNeLTkl
J9MKHzm1DdH5wRQWb5sDcfbZ4zjIUOniya01LBUwYrfj8cNthUnqodlrw3I/mVvzttPzIqXIweno4drk
5LE/g0DeI7Tmo3H1Ed9dXHHj18Vl60S25nnDxZkGL5MTcrOTXJVIkXjlLHr4rnVV6gPRnpsTl7SpJym4
peEddO5k5AEo8fuST9B6i+ghK/tVmVd8mpnFO0KnwjCUseHCXNavejxiT9C9BM+hYHJD7csTHUz1nfAo
QIWR+5epNPYYE9rDu/thIQzVUuYp8j1qhFkQpKl/UehBDElfMLi2MBCQE/F/ACXMqeEKZW5kc3RyZWFt
CmVuZG9iagoxOSAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvZHVjZXIgKHBkZlRlWC0xLjQwLjIxKQovQXV0aG9yKCkvVGl0
bGUoKS9TdWJqZWN0KCkvQ3JlYXRvcihMYVRlWCB3aXRoIGh5cGVycmVmKS9LZXl3b3JkcygpCi9DcmVh
dGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAyMDExMjAxNjEyNDIrMDEnMDAnKQovTW9kRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDIwMTEyMDE2MTI0
MiswMScwMCcpCi9UcmFwcGVkIC9GYWxzZQovUFRFWC5GdWxsYmFubmVyIChUaGlzIGlzIHBkZlRlWCwg
VmVyc2lvbiAzLjE0MTU5MjY1LTIuNi0xLjQwLjIxIChUZVggTGl2ZSAyMDIwKSBrcGF0aHNlYSB2ZXJz
aW9uIDYuMy4yKQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvT2JqU3RtCi9OIDE1Ci9GaXJzdCAx
MDAKL0xlbmd0aCA3NzEgICAgICAgCi9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp42q1U227T
QBB991fMYytUj/fiXVtCSGmiQEULqCnXKA/GWaUWqTeyNwL+npm1aZIiJB6QYsczc+bsXHZGQAYKlAAN
QpVgQVoBBSkUlKByA0KAKkvIQWtBENBlDiKHwppEZGQVBJH00yTwZ0GCZS76L0BoIZPnzwEXgC/9nQec
wVLRmbeA8yas4MULMid493PnAN9VG5fg1LfBtaEHw7gEb13v913tegoiKm7cuqku/Q9YZqQwdLwt5Soh
9478OJwIm7StJ5YlpcbnrZKTs6I1wcX+a4jyddN+S/DSd2vXRV6xwld4hdOlICFbcRx1gKXMdSqkAqN0
qizVy4g0Ky0YnadS5oSbwJOEz66Ce0jFOSc7xnCowqfPX6haMrWmAJvlaWag3W+3q78hVUQaY1NRFv8b
mqtU5qfIOXUjJjSX1P8sOpEJ33W+XjgqCLVtNge8cz/CUOOltDYtIM+yf34Gj+O3jW9tZSrH96CxeUZl
KlIFVkatUWkJpshSQ+FLRhQ6tRGnqDUCcsGIwdtQdqUwo33URd+RXRn2yHPWDPyMo0dk8vH4nC8dUx8S
ffp1VIJIprVO9cm3yvj7gBg8Rq08cBTUGzViDugBoUpBqagy8hVFWq6OLjg3bub6umt2wXdDI99UD2SZ
3X58M7l+Nr25FRnpt9WmBz0ALuNYXdAwX8iYdVZyvnyr+5qHy5SEnFa7V67Z3JNYKLpMbrBdCDZehWrb
1JN2s3VA9Au6+x/ILcFPo49Wgijuq46vzxlOcI5fscY1OmywRY++dbjDnesav8YOewwYvvvzIcJ5Q7wi
jvTpQLPxaJ5ZSedcVr2LV/hp1ifV4Y0Wd8a86frAsYE2CV5Xo0BbLsGPzTrc97wD/zibF1fPm2vP+yfB
1826HyfscZC49qQ8m/n6YhGqLpzTnuVpelwP5ZEoz3nzRnlH5Gy2Ax1tqocmPGH6DToMuOsJI8yfsU4r
apDfJEPQj9tyCE/YQWLbjV87fN+7t/uwbVrO7+3OtZM6NL4F8Zv4F5bzgjwKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9i
agoyMCAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvWFJlZgovSW5kZXggWzAgMjFdCi9TaXplIDIxCi9XIFsxIDIgMV0K
L1Jvb3QgMTggMCBSCi9JbmZvIDE5IDAgUgovSUQgWzw3QkM3NTU2RkRGRUFCMUE4QThEMUNFRjk3RDg1
NThBRD4gPDdCQzc1NTZGREZFQUIxQThBOEQxQ0VGOTdEODU1OEFEPl0KL0xlbmd0aCA2NSAgICAgICAg
Ci9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp42hXJyQ2AMBQDUfuzhJ0aaCBColOKjNIFTA5v
JMuSvlDI90XDCCTrbLtDjwELRqyYrNL+GRt2HM5Vfl79otMEywplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCnN0YXJ0
eHJlZgoxMzIwMgolJUVPRgo=
```

Comment: FWIW: The same happens when I open the document in Safari or Chrome, then choose to print and open a PDF preview. However, when I open them in ColorSync, there are no borders whatsoever.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a very simple PDF document that includes a link and share it over Dropbox or Google Drive? That would be make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: @jaume Thanks for trying to help me. In https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dbgwi5cvi3s0qr5/AAAWnwbmlJnGn_Igr5EvydWra you will find two files: the original and the "Print to PDF" variant with just a red rectangle, but no actual link in it.

Comment: Thank you, I can't really say if this is relevant, but after opening the PDF file (which in Preview on Big Sur also displays a red box) I've noticed that in the annotations tab (the one with a pencil) of the Info panel (press Command-<letter i> to open it), the link is listed with red color. I checked other PDF files with links, and there the color is grey. Could the red color be a setting in "hyperref"? I see the red box with Firefox (macOS) and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Windows) too, so it seems the problem is not constrained to Preview.

Comment: @jaume I think the formatting of the link is actually an option in hyperref. But for one, this has never been a problem (for years) before I switched to Catalina. The box being shown in Preview does not bother me. The problem is that it should disappear while printing. Also, when I open the PDF in Chrome or ColorSync, the red border does not show. In Chrome, the link still works. So I can currently only print my documents from Chrome or ColorSync, unfortunately. Oh

Comment: I understand that this issue started when you upgraded to Catalina, but wanted to make it clear that the red box is also displayed with other PDF viewers, including Adobe's own Acrobat Reader. So this seems to be more of a rendering issue than a Catalina issue. I understand this doesn't help much, but luckily you have a workaround, and I hope Chrome and ColorSync don't change the way they display links any time soon. In the long run, you may want to try to tweak hyperref's configuration.

Comment: I should have expressed myself better. The problem is not that those boxes are *shown*. They are supposed to be, because it us generally useful to make those links visible. The problem is that they are *printed*. This does not happen when I print them from Acrobat, Sumatra, Foxit or PDF Annotator. And it did not in previous versions of the Preview.app.

Comment: Of course, it's about printing, not rendering, the title of your question is pretty clear, sorry. I've tested it and Acrobat Reader doesn't print the box, but Preview does. So yes, this is a problem with Catalina's (and Big Sur's) Preview, and looks like a bug...